# JSON error loading

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save a simple name and load it – just to make everything clear to myself – there is no error, but when it loads it loads something different. It has something to do with Android itself.

Here is the class where I save and load (I don't use any libraries):

```java
public class Serializer
{
private Context context;
private String fn;
public Serializer(Context con , String filename){
    this.context = con;
    this.fn = filename;
}
public void save(ArrayList<String> usernames) throws JSONException, IOException {
    JSONArray JsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    for(String s : usernames){
        obj.put("username" , s);
        JsonArray.put(obj);
    }
    Writer writer = null;
    OutputStream out = context.openFileOutput(fn , 0);
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
    writer.write(JsonArray.toString());
    if(writer != null){
        writer.close();
    }
}
public  ArrayList<String> load () throws IOException, JSONException {
    ArrayList<String > strings = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStream in = context.openFileInput(fn);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String Line;
    while((Line = Reader.readLine() ) != null){
        builder.append(Line);
    }
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray)new JSONTokener(builder.toString()).nextValue();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
        String jack = (String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("username");
        strings.add(jack);
    }
    if(reader!=null){
        reader.close();
    }
    return strings;
}
}
```

Here is my main activity whose layout is a simple layout with one TextEdit:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Serializer serializer;
ArrayList<String> usernames;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    serializer = new Serializer(this,"Jacop");
    TextView txtView = findViewById(R.id.txt);
    usernames = new ArrayList<>();
    usernames.add(txtView.toString());
    try {
        ArrayList<String> username = serializer.load();
        txtView.setText(username.get(0));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    try {
        serializer.save(usernames);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The output (e.g what the text view shows after I close and reopen the app).

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{73d0e9d VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07007b app:id/txt}

Comment: i know it isn't perfect to use array here but because i will need to use it in the future so i wanted to train

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an `Object` as String .

```
usernames.add(txtView.toString());
```

Change it to

```
usernames.add(txtView.getText().toString());
```

`toString()` is a method of **Object** class so each class have it . and `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{73d0e9d VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07007b app:id/txt}` is the string representation of the `TextView` object .